# More efficient nested sum in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I am trying to calculate a vectorised nested sum

[image: equation]

(so effectively doing a separate calculation for each row *k*)

The fastest way I have come up with is to define a lower triangular matrix of ones to take into account the range on the inner sum

```
O = np.tril(np.ones((N,N),uint8),-1)
```

and then evaluate the inner sum with range *j=1..N*, allowing the use of a dot product

```
np.einsum('ij,ij->i',V,np.dot(W,O))
```

This works well, but even with *uint8* data type, *O* requires a lot of memory for N>>10000. Is there a better way using standard numpy/scipy functions? My plan is to run this on a GPU using cupy.

Comment: That's a lot of unnecessarily allocated 1s. Pretty sure this would be easy to do with numba.cuda + cupy.

Comment: I wondwr if rhe inner sum could be pre-calculated as a `cumsum`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @hpaulj, you can use `cumsum` to completely get rid of O. YOu can write sum W as total sum - cumsum.

```
O = np.sum(W,axis=1)[:,None]-np.cumsum(W,axis=1)
np.einsum('ij,ij->i',V,O)
```

Comment: Very slightly more efficient: `X = np.cumsum(W,axis=1); O = X[:,-1:]-X`

Comment: Very nice. Yeah, the sum is the last element of ```cumsum```, so you can avoid computing the ```sum```